# Oracle Application Express

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex

I want to install Oracle DB with Oracle APEX in XP.

I have some doubts regarding Apex:

- Can we connect this apex to other Databases installed on Different Machine.
- Can we install Apex without installing Oracle DB in the system for instance only installing apex in the system and later connecting it to DB in other system?

Please help me on this 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we connect this apex to other Databases installed on Different
>   Machine.

Depends on what you mean with this. If you just want to get (additional) data from another DB then you can do this with [a database link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_5005.htm) ([Docs: administrator's guide: database links](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/ds_concepts002.htm#ADMIN12083)).

> Can we install Apex without installing Oracle DB in the system for
>   instance only installing apex in the system and later connecting it to
>   DB in other system?

No. Apex is not some standalone executable, it is a database product. You can not have apex without the Oracle DB.

[Apex Docs: 2.1 Oracle Database Requirement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/install.42/e35123/pre_require.htm#BABFCFBC)

> Oracle Application Express release 4.2 requires an Oracle database
>   (Enterprise Edition, Standard Edition or Standard Edition One) that is
>   Release 10.2.0.4 or higher. Oracle Application Express 4.2 can also be
>   used with Oracle Database Express Edition 10g Release 2 and later. The
>   Oracle HTTP Server is not included with the distribution of Oracle
>   Database Express Edition.

Take a good look at the requirements so you know what you're getting in to. For example: what listener will you use?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have Some More Questions:
a) I want to Install Oracle 11g with APEX on XP, Does it come with any Web Server( eg. HTTP Apache Server with mod_plsql) or I need to install separately? 
b) Which web Server is good for Oracle 11g and APEX ??

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Ekta- You have couple of options, and they are listed in the apex docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/install.42/e35123/pre_require.htm#CFHIIJBE So the db comes with the embedded plsql gateway, but not with other software. If you want apache with modplsql you'll have to get that yourself. The apex listener is (also) a free product, and even though I'm no dba or admin, I'd say it works fine aswell. As for what is best, that depends on your requirements and knowledge of course.